# How to call two or more functions with formik.handleChange with onChange in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a sign in form with material-ui and validate the form using formik. The problem I'm having is that in the password textfield I have onChange function that toggles the password visibility on and off. In the same onChange I want to add formik.onChange function. How can I achieve that

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./SignIn.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import EmailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/EmailOutlined";
import VisibilityOnIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Visibility";
import VisibilityOffIcon from "@material-ui/icons/VisibilityOff";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";

import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";



let validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string("Enter your email")
    .email("Enter valid email")
    .required("Please fill in your email"),
  password: yup
    .string("Enter your password")
    // .password("Enter valid password")
    .required("Please enter your password"),
});

function SignIn() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [pwd, setPwd] = useState({
    password: "",
    showPassword: false,
  });

  const handleChange = (props) => (event) => {
    setPwd({ ...pwd, [props]: event.target.pwd });
  };

  const handleClickShowPassword = (event) => {
    setPwd({ ...pwd, showPassword: !pwd.showPassword });
  };

  const handleMouseDownPassword = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
  });

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="signIn">
        <div className="signIn__text">
          <h4>Sign In with your Email </h4>
        </div>

        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="signIn__form">
            <div className="signIn__email">
              <TextField
                className={classes.textField}
                // id="standard-required"
                id="email"
                label="Email"
                // defaultValue="Email"
                value={formik.values.email}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
                helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
                InputProps={{
                  className: classes.input,
                  endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                      <EmailIcon className={classes.icons} />
                    </InputAdornment>
                  ),
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="signIn__password">
              <TextField
                className={classes.textField}
                // id="standard-password-input"
                id="password"
                label="Password"
                name="password"
                // fullWidth
                type={pwd.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                value={pwd.password}
                onChange={handleChange("password")}
                error={
                  formik.touched.password && Boolean(formik.errors.password)
                }
                helperText={formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password}
                InputLabelProps={{
                  className: classes.floatingLabelStyle,
                  // shrink: true,
                }}
                InputProps={{
                  className: classes.input,
                  endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                      <IconButton
                        className={classes.iconBtn}
                        aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                        onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                        onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                      >
                        {pwd.showPassword ? (
                          <VisibilityOnIcon className={classes.icons} />
                        ) : (
                          <VisibilityOffIcon className={classes.icons} />
                        )}
                      </IconButton>
                    </InputAdornment>
                  ),
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="signIn__forgetPassword">
            <Link to="/resetPassword" className="signIn__forgetPasswordLink">
              <p className="signIn__forgetPassword__text">Forget Password</p>
            </Link>
          </div>

          <div className="signIn__button">
            <Button
              className={classes.margin}
              size="large"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
            >
              Sign In
            </Button>
          </div>

          <div className="signIn__signUp">
            <p className="signIn__new">New to KABBEE?</p>
            <Link to="/signUp" className="signIn__signUpLink">
              <p className="signIn__signUp__now"> Sign up now.</p>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default SignIn;
```

Comment: I made simplified version, dont know if it would be usefull for you
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-khorana-xq6xg

Comment: Thanks man..it worked. Really appreciate your help